# Can no longer dial the phone from macOS Safari

Tags: iphone, safari

I often use(d) the context menu that appears in Safari when you select a phone number on a web page and then ask it to dial using my iPhone.

Sometime in the last weeks (maybe months?) I can no longer trigger this. The only selections in the menu now are to open the call in FaceTime or send a Message.

BT is on, and my iPhone appears in the Finder.

I have looked in Security, Privacy and Advanced, and there does not appear to be a setting for this anywhere.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What version of macOS? What version of Safari What model iPhone running what version of iOS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mac: Facetime: File > Preferences> Enable 'Calls from iPhone'

iPhone: Settings> Phone> Calls on other Devices> enabled 'Allow Calls on Other Devices" and ensure that the name of your Mac is on the list and enabled.

Comment: Turns out the issue was that the macOS update logged me out of FT. Logged in and presto. Thanks!